# Use get to write file contents to another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, google-api

When I go to Googles stock api url as I listed below, I get an automatic file download. My goal is to take the automatically downloaded file contents and stream it to another file on my local system.

```
var get = require('get');

get('http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=NASDAQ%3aADBE&startdate=Jan+01%2C+2009&enddate=Aug+2%2C+2012&output=csv').asString(function(err, data) {
    var stream = fs.createWriteStream("./public/js/googl.csv");
      stream.once('open', function(fd) {
      stream.write(data);
      stream.end();
    });
});
```

I was able to accomplish this with another api link: [link](http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=INTC%20&a=6%20&b=10%20&c=2013%20&d=6%20&e=10%20&f=2013)

[http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=INTC &a=6 &b=10 &c=2013 &d=6 &e=10 &f=2013]

Both these api links do the same thing, output a csv file with stock data from the requested stock. My problem is, when I use googles api link it throws me an error and says it's 'unidentified'. I tried to log the data with console.log(data); and I do not get anything either. When I remove &output=csv it works but I receive a bunch of javascript that I assume is on the actual page. How can I grab the contents of the automatically downloaded file and store it within the data parameter of my get function?

Comment: Can you include the full error you're getting?

Comment: it works on chrome when simply browsing to the URL, so most likely, you just need to make your node request look more like a chrome request by spoofing the request headers.

Comment: Here is the error message:  _stream_writable.js:268
  var len = state.objectMode ? 1 : chunk.length;
                                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:268:41)
    at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:215:11)

Answer (score 0):

I switched from a get module to a request module and It worked, ex: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request Here is the function I used:

```
request('http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=NASDAQ%3aADBE&startdate=Jan+01%2C+2009&enddate=Aug+2%2C+2012&output=csv',     function (error, response, body) {
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) { 
    var stream = fs.createWriteStream("./public/js/googl.csv");
      stream.once('open', function(fd) {
      stream.write(body);
      stream.end();
    });
  }
});
```